# wildcards for elasticsearch simple_query_string?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, lucene

As a result of the following query to the type:

```
"query": {
     "simple_query_string" : {
          "query" : "RUDVRUMMXXX"
        }
  }
```

I get 5 hits. `RUDVRUMMXXX` is the entire text value of some field.

When I try to search with just a bit of its value (e.x. `VRUMMXXX`, or `VRUMMX`) elastic finds nothing.

I tried to add wildcard like that:

```
"query": {
     "simple_query_string" : {
          "query" : "*VRUMMXXX",
          "analyze_wildcard" : true
        }
  }
```

but get zero result anyway.

also tried this:

```
"query": {
     "wildcard" : {
          "query" : "*VRUMMXXX"
        }
  }
```

...same success.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 { 
   "query": 
      { 
         "query_string" : 
           { 
                 "query" : "*VRUMMXXX"
            } 
       } 
 }
```

Comment: Error:

"type": "query_parsing_exception",
"reason": "[_na] query malformed, no field after start_object"

Comment: still 0 hits :( I've substituted "some_field" with correct one